How can I improve the file reading time of large .nc files (70GB-350GB)?
I am working with ERA5 atmospheric data to calculate wind speeds anywhere globally, at maximum spatial and time resolution. This results in an uncompressed 70GB file for one year's worth of data, and I want to analyze 5 years in total, so it could quickly scale up.
In my application, I want to retrieve the entire time history data for a single spatial coordinate, which for one year results in a single [1x8760] array (from a total array of [721x1440x8760]). However, reading this data with xarray takes approximately 12s. This is too much time given that I want to make an API in which the user inputs the coordinates directly, and I still have to include 5 more years. Furthermore, I would like to scale up the data with different atmospheric pressures, and there would be more time overhead as the data would be stored in an external device. Here is a snippet of how the code works:
import xarray as xr                                                                
import dask.array as da                                                                                                                   
import time                                                                        

# Timer starts                                                                      
start = time.time()                                                                

# Specifying the coordinates                                                                               
lat = 1                                                                            
lon = 1                                                                            

# Opening the file                                          
ds = xr.open_dataset('2023Data.nc', engine='netcdf4')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                   
# For now the method of obtaining data is just by choosing the nearest point                             
u_region = ds.u.sel(lat=lat, lon=lon, method='nearest').data                       
v_region = ds.v.sel(lat=lat, lon=lon, method='nearest').data                                                                                  

# Converting the data into absolute velocity and angle                                                                                                                                                
abs_region = da.sqrt(u_region ** 2 + v_region ** 2)                                
theta = da.arctan2(u_region, v_region)                                                                                                                         
                                                                                   
print(abs_region, theta)                                                           
end = time.time()                                                                  
print(end - start)

Is there a way of indexing to retrieve this data faster? Are these reading times normal given the size of the data file and the query? Could it simply be a problem with my computer?
I have tried compressing it with cdo with the line chunks option to a deflate level 9, which resulted in higher overhead (I guess the compression was too deep, but I am not sure that the chunking helped). With cdo I have also tried to decrease the --resolution and the bit size -b, as I only need 3 decimals, but this did not even work.
I have also tried using dask's native chunking algorithm but I am not too sure that this is helping read only parts of the file. I am only trying to access one single coordinate, like the diagram on the left of the picture below, so I guess that with proper indexing the reading time could be drastically reduced.
NetCDF Data Access Patterns

Can you precise the dimensions (and coordinates) of ds ? print(ds) will be fine.

The dimensions are 721x1440x8760, I will make an edit

I'm slightly confused by the Q. If you are only interested in one data point, why is 12 seconds slow? Can you not just extract the data once? Why would you need to do it repeatedly?

@RobertWilson because it needs to be based on query: I am building an API that needs to fetch the data, but the coordinates will be specified by the user. As for the 12s, I do not know if that is slow or fast in context, but I need something faster in order to scale it.

That kind of info is needed in the Q. It's hard to answer the question given the info. For example, you could split the file up into a large number of files with different spatial domains and just get the api to access the one the coordinate is in. But we can't tell if such approaches are acceptable

Thanks @Robert, I will add it. I was thinking of splitting up the files for a faster reading but I do not know if that would be very messy. I have added the spatial resolution above. What sort of splitting dimensions would you recommend?

These things are up to you. I cannot recommend something without knowing specific limitations. But, you are doing nearest neighbour, and you are dealing with a rectangular grid. If speed is essential, you can make each non-missing grid point a separate file and then create a lookup table to go from lonlat to file.

The key issue is the chunking of your original data. In order to extract any single point, a chunk of data will need to be read and decoded. Let's say your data has chunking like [1x360x2190], which would equate to 6MB/chunk in memory for int/float64. In this case, each point of your output 1D array would require reading and decompression/decoding of 6MB's worth of data (the on-disk size of this depends on compression), so your process needs to scan through 8760x6MB = 52GB of data. Again, this was for 64-bit values and my guess at what your chunking might be.
Note that you cannot change the chunking of the data without rewriting it. There are tools like rechunker to help with that, if you need to. Aligning your access pattern and the chunking is a general conversation all by itself.
Note that if you are finding that dask is not providing decent parallelism, you could try scanning your file with kerchunk. However, I suspect this will make little difference and you are bottlenecked by the disk and memory speeds.

So if I rechunk the data file and I open it with open_mfdataset, the chunk geometries should match, right? Or at least the dask chunks should be subdivisions of the original data chunks, no?

Hello @mdurant, I have looked into rechunker and I am trying to rechunk it according to my specifications (10x10x8760). Right now I am trying with a smaller file (721x1440x744) with chunk sizes of (10x10x744). The rechunking is done relatively fast (1.5min), but as I try to convert the .zarr back to .nc it takes a taxatively long time. Would I be able to work with .zarr for better reading speeds, or should I find another way to rechunk the data?

.nc may well not support parallel writing, but zarr does. Zarr also fares better in remote storage, but is less well known and supported.

thanks for the help @mdurant. are you familiar with nccopy and ncks? I have posted another question because I am also having trouble chunking. Feel free to take a look if you are feeling charitable ;)).

Sorry, I don't use those tools. Rechunker->zarr may well be your best choice unless you have other constraints.

I tried using rechunker and zarr, but after 13h it was still 41% done. Are those times right for the size of the file @mdurant?

I imagine it depends on a lot of things. There should be some feedback on reasonable settings. It was designed to be able to work with massive parallelism in systems like lambda.
